# AutoMapper.Reset() is needed after an update

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, automapper

I'm using AutoMapper in an MVC app.
In GET I need to show a list of object and map them like that:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Word, WordViewModel>();
Mapper.Map<IList<Word>, IList<WordViewModel>>(list);
```

then, the user can edit and save, int the POST I do the following

```
Mapper.CreateMap<WordViewModel, Word>();
```

Everything is ok. But when I'm trying to get the list again AutoMapper says that it isn't able to perform the mapping correctly.

I solved calling AutoMapper.Reset() as soon as I don't need it anymore. But I'm not sure that is the correct workflow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should only create the maps once during `Application_Start` and not use `Reset`. For example:

**Global.axac.cs**

```cs
protected void Application_Start()
{
    Mapper.Initialize(x => x.AddProfile<ViewProfile>());
}
```

**AutoMapper Configuration**

```cs
public class ViewProfile : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<Word, WordViewModel>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<WordViewModel, Word>();
    }
}
```

Make sure you include a unit test to validate your mappings:

```cs
[TestFixture]
public class MappingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void AutoMapper_Configuration_IsValid()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(m => m.AddProfile<ViewProfile>());
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    }
}
```

Then just call the `Mapper.Map` as required in your application.

Comment: Thank you. What about I'm using AutoMapper in Data Access Layer that doesn't have access to Application_Start? I wish to avoid a reference from the presentation layer to DAL just to do that.

Comment: That's where the profiles come in (well, how I use them anyway). I create a DAL profile for the data layer, and a View profile for the view models, and simply initialise them where appropriate (ie, in app start or unit test, etc). You can also initialise them via IoC, but I've never done that. If you prefer to do that, then check out this [post on Jimmy's blog](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/05/12/automapper-and-ioc/) for a good starting point.